# Why does this code not work with Bubble sort

Tags: assembly, arm, bubble-sort

> These variable has ALREADY been defined:
>
> ```
>   int i, k, Done;     int A[];                // Array to be sorted   int N;          // contains the length of the array
> ```
>
> Write the following Bubble Sort algorithm in ARM assembler
>
> ```
>    Done = 0;             // 0 represents false
>    k = 1;
>
>    while (Done == 0) 
>    {  
>       Done = 1;          // 1 represents true.
>
>       for (i = 0; i < N-k; i++)
>       { 
>          if (A[i] > A[i+1])
>          { 
>    Swap A[i] and A[i+1];  // Use registers to swap value
>              Done = 0;            // Inidcate not sorted
>    }    }
>       k = k + 1;
>    }
> ```
>
> NOTE:  All variables used in the program have ALREADY been
> defined for you
> DO NOT define any new variables in the code.    ============================================================= */

```
        .global main, Stop, CodeEnd, DataStart, DataEnd

   main:
    MOV r4, #0
    MOV r5, #1
    LDR r7, =N

OuterLoop:
    MOV r4, #1

    MOV r6, #0

InnerLoop:
    LDR r8, =N
    SUB r8, r8, r5
    CMP r6, r8
    BGE UpdateK

    LDR r9, =A

    MOV r10, r6
    LSL r10, r10, #2
    ADD r9, r9, r10

    LDR r11, [r9]
    ADD r10, r6, #1
    LSL r10, r10, #2
    ADD r9, r9, r10

    LDR r12, [r9]

    CMP r11, r12
    BLE NoSwap

    STR r12, [r9, #-4]
    STR r11, [r9]

    MOV r4, #0

NoSwap:
    ADD r6, r6, #1
    B InnerLoop

UpdateK:
    ADD r5, r5, #1
    MOV r6, #0
    B OuterLoop
     



Stop:
    nop

CodeEnd:


/*********************************************************************
   DO NOT make any changed to the code below this line

   The include file "variables.h" contains the variable definitions for

        int i, k, Done;
        int A[];                // Array to be sorted
        int N;                  // contains the length of the array
 *********************************************************************/

#include "variables.h"

.end
```

This code compiles successfully but the array does not change after i run it.

Comment: Which part is the homework assignment and which part did you do yourself?